# Write a Mock method applicable only for specific tests in a test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a test class in which I have around 10 unit test cases. In this, I have a **mock method** created which is **useful in just 2 of the 10 test cases**.

```
public static class MockCreateStudent extends Mockup<CreateStudentDAO>{
    @Mock
    public boolean isFeesPaid(long studentID){
        return true;
    }
}
```

So technically I want the `isFeesPaid()` method to be executed as-is for 8 test cases and mocked for 2 of the test cases.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: That doesn't sound right - why do you only mock the collaborator under certain circumstances?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I just mentioned a simplified version of my actual problem statement above. Practically the isFeesPaid() method takes 4 parameters and populating them is a tedious task. 

For the 2 test cases that I'm talking about, this method isn't significant. So I'm trying to make it simpler by mocking it. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a spy in that case instead of a mock. For most of the cases, it will invoke the real implementation of the collaborator and for those 2 cases, you use the `given().willReturn()` stubbing in the `//Given` section just before you invoke the SUT.

Here is more info on the spy annotation which I would recommend you use: [link](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Spy.html)